# Realm update one object and others instance is also updated

Tags: java, android, realm

I have Class Orders:

```
public class Order extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("Id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("Contractor")
private Contractor contractor;
@SerializedName("ItemAmounts")
private RealmList<ItemAmount> itemsAmounts = new RealmList<>();
@SerializedName("ModificationDate")
private Date modificationDate;
@SerializedName("ExportDate")
private Date exportDate;
@SerializedName("Export")
private boolean exportStatus;
@SerializedName("User")
private User user;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Contractor getContractor() {
    return contractor;
}

public void setContractor(Contractor contractor) {
    this.contractor = contractor;
}

public RealmList<ItemAmount> getItemsAmounts() {
    return itemsAmounts;
}


public void setItemsAmounts(RealmList<ItemAmount> itemsAmounts) {
    this.itemsAmounts = itemsAmounts;
}

public Date getModificationDate() {
    return modificationDate;
}

public void setModificationDate(Date modificationDate) {
    this.modificationDate = modificationDate;
}

public Date getExportDate() {
    return exportDate;
}

public void setExportDate(Date exportDate) {
    this.exportDate = exportDate;
}

public boolean isExportStatus() {
    return exportStatus;
}

public void setExportStatus(boolean exportStatus) {
    this.exportStatus = exportStatus;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

}
And i Create any new order save to Realm:

```
  public void insertOrUpdate(Order order) {
    Order orderToCompare = realm.where(Order.class)
            .equalTo("id", order.getId()).findFirst();


    realm.beginTransaction();
    if (orderToCompare == null) {
        Order orderRealm = realm.createObject(Order.class, order.getId());
        orderRealm.setExportStatus(order.isExportStatus());
        orderRealm.setContractor(order.getContractor());
        orderRealm.setModificationDate(order.getModificationDate());
    } else if (!orderToCompare.equals(order)) {
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(order);
    }

    realm.commitTransaction();


}
```

All my Orders have List of ItemAmount and ItemAmount have single item(Items is also contains in Realm) and his amount. So when i try change the amount of item in one order all my amount in others ItemAmount is updated. Below its function which I update the amount:

```
     recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            itemPosition = position;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OrderItemsActivity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.change_amount, null);
            builder.setView(mView);
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            Button changeAmountButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.changeAmountButton);
            final EditText setAmountEditText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.setAmountEditText);

            changeAmountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (setAmountEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pole nie może być puste", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        orderDAO = new OrderDAO();
                        orderDAO.updateAmountOfItem(Integer.parseInt(setAmountEditText.getText().toString()), itemPosition, selectedOrderId);
                        itemAmounts.clear();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                        prepareOrderData();

                    }

                }
            });
        }

 public void updateAmountOfItem(int amount, int itemPosition, int orderId) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    Order orderToCompare = realm.where(Order.class)
            .equalTo("id", orderId).findFirst();
    orderToCompare = realm.copyFromRealm(orderToCompare);
    RealmList<ItemAmount> itemAmounts = orderToCompare.getItemsAmounts();
    ItemAmount itemAmount = itemAmounts.get(itemPosition);
    itemAmount.setAmount(amount);
    itemAmounts.set(itemPosition,itemAmount);
    orderToCompare.setItemsAmounts(itemAmounts);
    realm.insertOrUpdate(orderToCompare);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

How fix it? Because i need update only one instance, not all of them.

Comment: You didn't ask a question, you just stated the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry you are right I already add question.

Comment: Does your `ItemAmount` have a primary key?

Comment: Yes its have. But i don't create `ItemAmount` directly in Realm, I create new object and pass it to `RealmList <ItemAmount>`.

Comment: I thought about your question and I turn off primary key for `ItemAmount` and after that its began to act as I wanted. But i'm still don't know how Primary Key affect `ItemAmount` inside others object.